# How do i translate a message to an empty string with django

Tags: python, django, localization, translation

I am using django 1.27 with python 2.7.2.
I want a message to be translated to an empty string.

For example if i have this in my django.po file:

```
# .\path\file.py
msgid "word"
msgstr ""
```

So i want it to not show the 'word' when translating the page.

I have tried putting a space instead of "" but that did not help and i still get the original 'word' displayed.
How can i do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

django's translation process is based on the GNU gettext toolset. This a gettext bug many people have complained.

There is a workaround that you can translate them to invisible unicode characters like U+200B, U+180E, U+2063

Comment: I have the same problem (but with php). Where can I find the bug report on gettext for this?

Answer (score 0):

Putting a space `" "` instead of `""` works for me (Django 1.6, Python 3.2). Are you sure you've done `django-admin.py compilemessages` and reloaded the server after changing the translation?

```
# .\path\file.py
msgid "word"
msgstr " "
```